# Accessing parent directive's controller recursively in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to get parent's controller, so my directive has a require property, as follows:

```js
module.directive('tag', function () {
    return {
        require: '?^tag',
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function () {
            this.payload = getPayload();
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            usePayload(ctrl.payload);
        }
    };
});
```

However the ctrl parameter of the link function returns the controller of the current directive, not the parent's one. AngularJS documentation is clear about this:

> ?^ - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element's parents, or return null if not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `require: '?^parent'` or assign directive's controller to the name of the parent controller or leave off the directive's controller all together and `ctrl` in the link parameters will default to the parent.

Comment: Have a look at this video by [John Lindquist](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication) which explains communicating between nested directives pretty well.

Comment: @m.e.conroy: I have to use the same name in `require`. If no controller is declared, `ctrl` defaults to `undefined`.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo: That example is not recursive meaning the directive names are different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either the docs or the code are misleading here... `require` with `^` looks at the current element and then all parent, using the `inheritedData` method (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L942). So you won't be able to require a directive with the same name from a parent using this approach.

When I've had this issue in the past I've looked at the `form` directive which needs to do what you are asking. Its controller method grabs the parent like so (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L39):

```
controller: function($element) {
    var parentForm = $element.parent().controller('form');
}
```

Taking this, you should be able to call `element.parent().controller('tag')` to find the parent controller either in the controller or postLink methods.

Comment: This works, thanks! My only concern is that the `controller()` method is not exposed in their API, so not intended for public use and may be subject to change.

Comment: Docs can be found buried in those for `angular.element`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element. This is definitely documented in the unstable branches but I haven't checked stable.

Comment: This is so helpful. Thanks, i wanted to make an element that could act as a container for itself, so, this is perfect. Also, I've read it's not a good idea to pass the element to the controller so you could always work with the element in the link function